# Reading multiple urls does not work in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to webscrape a few urls. This is what I do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_2021_int = ["https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/inter/date/2021/html/index_include.en.html","https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/inter/date/2020/html/index_include.en.html", "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/inter/date/2019/html/index_include.en.html", "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/inter/date/2018/html/index_include.en.html", "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/inter/date/2017/html/index_include.en.html"]

for url in url_2021_int:
    req_int = requests.get(url)
    
soup_int = BeautifulSoup(req_int.text)
titles_int = soup_int.select(".title a")
titles_int=[data.text for data in titles_int]
```

However, I get data only for the last url (2017).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `req_int` in `req_int = requests.get(url)` is re-written each time in the loop.

Comment: You missed tabulation on the last three lines

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew how do you store the output then?

Comment: Why not process all in the loop you have? Or just create  a list. `req_ints = [requests.get(url) for url in url_2021_int]`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `req_int = requests.get(url)` in the loop, the `req_int` variable is re-written each time.

If you want to store the `requests.get(url)` results in a list variable you can use

```py
req_ints = [requests.get(url) for url in url_2021_int]
```

However, it seems logical to process the data in the same loop:

```py
for url in url_2021_int:
    req_int = requests.get(url)
    soup_int = BeautifulSoup(req_int.text, "html.parser")
    titles_int = soup_int.select(".title a")
    titles_int=[data.text for data in titles_int]
```

Note that you can specify the `"html.parser"` as a second argument to the `BeautifulSoup` call, since the documents you are parsing are HTML documents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With the first code it works but then it props up an error when trying to apply `BeautifulSoup()`, while with the second one `titles_int` is an empty object

Comment: @Rollo99 I helped to fix the immediate error. The rest is up to you to debug and fix. I just ran the code as is, and it seems to output values. There are quite a lot of items in each `titles_int`.